# create and fill an Shape type array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to create a Shape type array in a different class and fill the array with Shape objects

tried to create a Sphere type of Shape but i cannot use the methods of the Sphere and Shape class

Comment: add some example of code with details what have you tried and what is expected result

Answer (score 0):

Just creating and populating an Array of Shape should not be too difficult.
Be aware that Shape itself is abstract, so you need to populate the Array with concrete subclasses.

```
java.awt.Shape[] shapes = new java.awt.Shape[3];
shapes[0] =  new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, -1, -1);
shapes[1] = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double(5, 3, 11, 11);
shapes[2] = new java.awt.geom.Line2D.Float(11, 5, 3, 7);
```